# Android Tab navigation without tab title

Tags: android, tabs, actionbarsherlock

I'm using actionBarSherlock to create an app with tabs. But I want the tabs to be only and indicator with no text, no icon, no nothing. User may pass from tab to tab by swipping. I want a small tab indicator and nothing else.

Is there any way I can do this?

Also I want it to be backward compatible with gingerbread.

Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can build the layout like this then replace the fragment in the container on swipe and button OnClick

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<LinearLayout
    style="?android:attr/buttonBarStyle"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/tab1"
        style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="33"
        android:onClick="showfrag1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/tab2"
        style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="33"
        android:onClick="showfrag2" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/tab3"
        style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="33"
        android:onClick="showfrag3" />
</LinearLayout>

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll try it and let you know!